# Not getting data in UITableView from web service

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm fairly new with handling request and response in swift.. This is the code i'm stuck with. I'm getting the value from the webservice in dataArray but doesn't load in the tableview. Please someone help.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class AddOnsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataArray = [AnyObject]()
    var addOnsURL = "http://econstrademosite.com/food_delivery/?****************"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        callData()
    }

    @IBAction func goBackToHome(sender: UIBarButtonItem){

        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "base") as! SWRevealViewController
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func callData(){

        Alamofire.request(addOnsURL).responseJSON { response in

            let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let innerDict = dict["data"]?["result"]{
                    self.dataArray = innerDict as! [AnyObject]
                    print(self.dataArray)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(dataArray.count)
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! exampleTableViewCell
        let itemName = dataArray[indexPath.row]["item_name"]
        cell.label.text! = itemName as! String

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: i think u need to reload the table view in your request closure.

Comment: @koropok you are right

Comment: yes.. Thank you very much.. it worked.. needed to reload in the request closure..

Comment: @K.Mitra - accpet any one answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    func callData(){

        Alamofire.request(addOnsURL).responseJSON { response in

            let result = response.result
            if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let innerDict = dict["data"]?["result"]{
                    self.dataArray = innerDict as! [AnyObject]
                    print(self.dataArray)
                 if self.dataArray.count > 0
                  {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                  }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add `delegate` and `dataSource` for your `tableView`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        callData()
    }
```

and then reload tableView after data has been fetched:

```
func callData(){

    Alamofire.request(addOnsURL).responseJSON { response in

        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
            if let innerDict = dict["data"]?["result"]{
                self.dataArray = innerDict as! [AnyObject]
                print(self.dataArray)
                self.tableView.reloadData() // you missing this method
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already added delegate and datasource to the view.. and thanks it worked.. I was using the reload method in wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your tableview.reloadData() call. As soon as response comes after api call and you store the response in `dataArray`, you can reload the table.

So there is no point in reloading tableview in viewDidLoad() in your case as your `dataArray` is empty .

So please change the `callData()` method like this

```
func callData(){

    Alamofire.request(addOnsURL).responseJSON { response in

        let result = response.result
        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
            if let innerDict = dict["data"]?["result"]{
                self.dataArray = innerDict as! [AnyObject]
                print(self.dataArray)
            }
        }
    }
}
```